# Broken characters when returning a string from NAPI

Tags: node.js, string, utf-8, cjk, node-addon-api

I am trying to wrap C++ code with NAPI (Node addon API).
While writing the code, I faced the following problem.

**When returning a string from napi side to js side,
Non-English (Korean/Japanese/Chinese) strings are displayed as broken.**

Is there any way to solve this?
Any solutions or ideas would be appreciated!

The code is:
(NAPI side)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "wrapper.h"

Napi::Value wrapper::getNameWrapper(const Napi::CallbackInfo &info)
{
    Napi::Env env = info.Env();
    std::string dcmFilePath = info[0].As<Napi::String>().Utf8Value();
    Napi::String name = Napi::String::New(env, wrapper::getName(dcmFilePath));
    return patientName;
}

std::string wrapper::getName(std::string dcmFilePath)
{
    std::stringstream returnStringStream;
    returnStringStream << "김한춘"; // Non-English string (Korean)_
    return returnStringStream.str();
}

Napi::Object wrapper::Init(Napi::Env env, Napi::Object exports)
{
    exports.Set("getName", Napi::Function::New(env, wrapper::getNameWrapper));
    return exports;
}
```

(js side)

```js
const wrapper = require('./build/Release/wrapper.node')

console.log('wrapper: ', wrapper)
let name = wrapper.getName('C:/Users/p1h2c/Desktop/R2DATA/金韓春/DCT0000.dcm')
console.log('getName: ', name) // I expected '김한춘' but show '김?�춘'

module.exports = wrapper
```

Comment: *I expected '김한춘' but show 'break characters'*. Really? Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]. Maybe you see `ê¹€í•œì¶˜` or alike?

Comment: Oh I'm so sorry. my console printed the follow message: 김?�춘